# SQL: time_diff returns wrong value when value is not in the same year

Tags: mysql, sql

With the following query I want to select all adverts which have exceeded the allowed time of duration (saved as seconds) and are not active anymore:

```
SELECT * 
FROM adverts 
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(now(),adverts.stamp_created))>adverts.duration
```

My problem: If the time when the advert was created (= stamp_created, TIMESTAMP) is in this year, this query works correctly and the time_to_sec function gives back the correct time difference in seconds.

However, if the time when the advert was created is in a different year than the current one, for example in 2014, I get a wrong value for the time difference and the query does not work. What could be the reason? How do I need to adjust my query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about rephrasing the condition by adding seconds, rather than taking a difference?

```
SELECT * 
FROM adverts a
WHERE DATE_ADD(a.stamp_created, interval a.duration second) > NOW();
```